# Is there a way in VBScript to tell if it's running as a 32 or 64 bit process?

Tags: vbscript, 64-bit

Is there a function available from VBScript that tells you if the script interpreter (CScript / WScript) is running as a 32 or 64 bit process?

I see from other answers that in .NET you can use .Environment.Is64BitProcess which *does exactly what it says on the tin*.

**Edit:** I am now satisfied there is no trivial way to do this. Fortunately I use, from the script, a COM object written by me in C++; so I can trivially add a function to that. That's what I'm going to do now. But I'd rather use a more native solution if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I wrote this (along with some COM boilerplate):

```
unsigned Environment::GetProcessBits()
    {
        return sizeof(std::ptrdiff_t) /*size in bytes*/ * 8U;
    }
```

I like it as it avoids the preprocessor and I could even qualify with `constexpr` if msvc2012 supported it.

Answer (score 4):

At first I thought you could look at the `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE` environment variable:

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set colSystemEnvVars = objShell.Environment("System")
WSCript.Echo "System = " & colSystemEnvVars("PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE")
```

On a 32-bit command prompt on a 64-bit OS (i.e., CMD.EXE started from SysWow64), it returns x86 rather than AMD64. However it appears that from within a 32-bit CSCRIPT that's started from a 64-bit CMD.EXE it still returns AMD64.

So the only other way (and it's a bit of a hack in my opinion - mostly as assuming things from paths always seems bad, but this is probably static enough to be reliable) is to combine this with looking where the CSCRIPT was launched from:

```
WScript.Echo WScript.FullName
```

...if `WScript.FullName` contains SysWOW64, then it's a 32-bit cscript on a 64-bit box (most likely). If it contains System32 then you can fall back to the PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE environment variable.

**Addendum**
I've recently had a new machine running Windows 7 64-bit and this provides further possibilities (the original answer was based on a 64-bit Server 2008 box). There is now a new environment variable `PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432`. Quick experiments show that:

- 64-bit cmd.exe: `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64` and `PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432` is unset
- 32-bit cmd.exe: `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=x86` and `PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432=AMD64`

Comment: +1; probably the best you can do without messing about with a COM object over which you have control. And you now have 10K rep!

Answer (score 2):

If you ask for "PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE" in the "Process" (instead of the "System") group:

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set colSystemEnvVars = objShell.Environment("Process")
WSCript.Echo "System = " & colSystemEnvVars("PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE")
WScript.Echo WScript.FullName
```

you get (32 bit shell)

```
System = x86
  Host = C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CScript.exe
```

or (64 bit shell)

```
System = AMD64
  Host = C:\Windows\System32\CScript.exe
```